# YII: Need to combine these two If statements?

Tags: php, if-statement, yii, conditional-statements

I'm using the Yii framework. 
I want to show specific content if a user did not select their location.

So, I am using the following code to show content if no state is selected:

```
    <?php if ($state == NULL) { ?>
```

And I am using the following code if no city is selected:

```
    <?php if ($city == NULL) { ?>
```

And they are working perfectly, but how can I combine those two statements so that I can show content if they have no state, AND, no city selected?

Comment: You could have at least tried using google, very basic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<?php if ($city == NULL && $state == NULL) { ?>`
I suggest that you read about [operators in PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php). Also worth reading is the [PHP symbol reference FAQ of SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php).

Answer (score 1):

There are ***four*** different cases:

- both statements are true
- the first is true
- the second is true
- none are true

```
if($state == NULL && $city == NULL) {
    // both are true
}
else if($state == NULL) {

}
else if{$city == NULL) {

}
else{
   // neither is true, i.e. both are selected
}
```

The order in which they are listed is important: You ***must*** check for the case that both conditions are true first!

For more information, see the [**PHP documentation on logical operators**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php): *AND*, *OR*, *XOR*, *NOT*.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($city == NULL && $state == NULL)
```

[Logical Connective](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_connective)

The `&&` means `AND`
`||` would be `OR`